# Which of the following is grammatically correct and why?

Tags: word-order, interrogatives

1) Tell me, what would you have done?

2) Tell me, what you would have done?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence has a subclause that is a question, i.e. "What would you have done?" When you embed this question into a question, the word order in the question does not change: "Tell me, what would you have done?" This is grammatically correct question.

The clause "what you would have done" is not a question but can be embedded in another sentence. In that cause, it becomes the object of the verb "tell". So you get "Tell me what you would have done", without a comma or a question mark. The result is called an [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#English).

**Note**: The change in order from e.g. "English is fun" to "Is English fun?" is known as [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics)#In_English). Something similar, but with different subjects, is the difference in word order in "What time is it?" versus "It is 9 a.m.", or the difference in word order of "What would you have done?" versus (for example) "I would have stayed." In these questions, the main verb comes before the grammatical subject.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's very informative. Could you please explain this scenario: "Could you please tell me what the time is." Why is the "what is the time" changed into "what the time is" and when can we do it?

Comment: @Shivam This is something called "inversion" and I have added a few examples.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in such detail. Would you be so kind as to point out the difference in structure of "what time is it?" and "what is the time?".

Comment: @Shivam Please see the question [“What time is it” versus “what is the time”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/48175/37759).